# Why does nothing is loaded Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

When I'm going to "view" view, nothing is loaded, even the default layout, which contains the HTML header and footer, so it displays nothing in source code.

Code from controllers:

```
    public function actionArt($type){
        $compositions = Compositions::find()
            ->select(['id', 'name'])
            ->where('type' == $type)
            ->asArray()
            ->all();

        return $this->render('art', ['compositions' => $compositions]);
    }

    public function actionView($id){
        $info = Compositions::find()->where($id)->all();
        $this->render('view', ['info' => $info]);
    }
```

Code from views:

"ART" VIEW:

```
<?php

/* @var $compositions */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

?>

<div class="site-art">
    <?php foreach ($compositions as $composition){
        Html::a(Html::encode($composition['name']), ['site/info', 'id' => $composition['id']]);
        echo "<a href='" . Url::to(['site/view', 'id' => $composition['id']], true) . "'>{$composition['name']}</a><br>";
    } ?>
</div>
```

"VIEW" VIEW:

```
<?php

/* @var $info */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

var_dump($info);

?>

<div class="site-info">
    hwerasjdajsdajsk
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must **return** the result of `render()`, not just call it.

```
return $this->render('view', ['info' => $info]);
```

Also this

```
Html::a(Html::encode($composition['name']), ['site/info', 'id' => $composition['id']]);
```

does nothing now. You must echo it so it will basically do the same that line below it does now. But better because it html-encodes the `$composition['name']`.